# issue with array indexing

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, arrays

So I'll jump right to it...
I am a test automation engineer, and I am making a "keyword driven" testing system that is powered with JSON, which tie in with Selenium tests to run on a web browser.

The "keywords" are stored as XML files, and I have a JavaScript function which loads these keywords into an array, and also stores the Index of that keyword. to paf.keywordIndex

#### Example

---

```
$.get("getSteps.php", function(keywords) {
            paf.keywords = eval(keywords); // stores into an array...

            paf.keywordIndex = -1;
            for ( var i = 0 ; i < paf.keywords.length ; i++ ) {

                // for each path...
                /* alert(paf.keywords[i]); */

                $.ajax({url: "./_keywords/" + paf.keywords[i], success: function(xml) {         
                    paf.xml = xml;

                    paf.keywordIndex++;
                    var title = $(xml).find("keyword").attr("title");
                    //var name = $(xml).find("keyword").attr("name");

                    paf.buffer += ("<option value=\"./_keywords/"+paf.keywords[paf.keywordIndex]+"\">"+title+"</option>");
                },
                async: false
                //cache: false
                });

            }

            $(stepSelectionLocator).html(paf.buffer);
        });
```

`getSteps.php` is a php service that returns all the xml keywords in a json array. e.g.
`["Login.xml","EndSession.xml", "SelectResult.xml", etc...]`

---

Now this function works, but the only problem is, it's not sorted in ANY way. So the output would be -

- Login           (Login.xml)
- Select a result (SelectResult.xml)
- End a session   (EndSession.xml)

---

To solve this issue, I added an extra attribute to my `<keyword>` so now it's `<keyword area="basic">` to indicate that this is a basic step. and now my function is -

```
$.get("getSteps.php", function(keywords) {
            paf.keywords = eval(keywords); // stores into an array...

            paf.keywordIndex = -1;
            for ( var i = 0 ; i < paf.keywords.length ; i++ ) {

                // for each path...
                /* alert(paf.keywords[i]); */



                $.ajax({url: "./_keywords/" + paf.keywords[i], success: function(xml) {         
                    paf.xml = xml;

                    paf.keywordIndex++;
                    var title = $(xml).find("keyword").attr("title");
                    var area = $(xml).find("keyword").attr("area");
                    //var name = $(xml).find("keyword").attr("name");

                    paf.buffer.push(area.toUpperCase() + ": " + title);
                },
                async: false
                //cache: false
                });

            }

            paf.buffer.sort(); // array is sorted...



            paf.buffer2 = "";
            paf.keywordIndex = -1;
            for ( var a in paf.buffer ) {
                paf.keywordIndex++;
                paf.buffer2 += "<option value=\"./_keywords/"+paf.keywords[paf.keywordIndex]+"\">"+ paf.buffer[a] + "</option>"; 
            }

            $(stepSelectionLocator).html(paf.buffer2.toString().replace(",", ""));
        });
```

Now the output is

- BASIC: End the session (Login.xml)
- BASIC: Login (SelectResult.xml)
- RESULTS: Select a result (EndSession.xml)

So I've already determined that the index is the issue. However, I cannot figure out a way to fix this..

I am open to alternatives, so if you find a simpler way to index this, please let me know!

Comment: This has nothing to do with answering the question, but I'd suggest using `JSON.parse();` instead of `eval();`.

Comment: not sure why Andrew removed the QA tag.. any QA resources that do automation, might be relevant to them. oh well.

Comment: By the way, why do you iterate over the `paf.buffer` array with `for in` instead of `for (var a = 0; a < paf.buffer.length; a++) {...}`

Comment: Don't know if that's what you want, but [here's](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml) a nice explanation of array sorting, showing how to pass a function to the `sort` function so it sorts the way you need.

Comment: @anderson.pimentel i actually used that specific tutorial for learning how to do this.. however the sorting isn't my problem, it's the index that is now out of sync.

Comment: Is the following fiddle of any help: http://jsfiddle.net/6nfyT/2/ ?

Comment: It looks VERY promising... working on something else, but will surely get back to you...  Feel free to post that as the answer, because it'd most likely be it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it'd be nice to know *exactly* the data you get from your initial request.

```
$.get("getSteps.php", function (keywords) {
    paf.keywords = JSON.parse(keywords); // eval is bad! Use JSON.parse instead.
    console.log(paf.keywords); // what does it output in the console?
    ...
```

Secondly, you can refer to the current index by using just the `i` variable. If you don't use `paf.keywordIndex` elsewhere, you can remove it because it's redundant.

Thirdly, are you absolutely, definitely, 100% sure that your ajax requests are ***S***ynchronous? **If they are not - the responses will arrive at random** and the whole thing will require a different approach.

Finally, if you want to apply sorting to your keywords after you got them all, I would recommend pushing them into the buffer array as objects:

```
buffer.push({
    keyword: keywordName, // this is the keyword name
    keywordIndex: i, // this is the initial index
    keywordArea: areaObtainedFromXML // this is the area you get from xml
});
```

By using the above approach you will be able to sort your buffer in many ways while retaining the initial order.

Please take a look at a contrived example at **[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nfyT/2/)**.

Comment: never thought of pushing that to the array... also - i did show you exactly what you get from the initial request

Comment: thirdly, i am absolute definitely 100% sure i want synchronous.. if it's async it returns the files at random.

Comment: Then how do you get from Login-EndSession-SelectResult to Login-SelectResult-EndSession in your first example? It should return them in the same order.